# I'm getting my average but the print is not how I would like to have it. How can I solve it differently?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregate, average

I made a connection to my MongoDB and I want to get the average from all my likes.
The print looks like this:

```
Tweets average from likes:

results: [Document{{_id=null, average=143.0}}]
```

**The way I want my print is:** `results: 143.0`

My doc looks like this:

```
static MongoCollection<Document> doc = db.getCollection(mongodbCollection);
```

Should I used my tweetCollection?

```
static MongoCollection<Tweet> tweetCollection = db.getCollection("tweetsDB", Tweet.class);
```

It tells me that I need to have type Document in my List, but then the print doesn't look the way I want it. How can I do it differently?

```
public static void averageFromLikes(MongoCollection<Tweet> tweetCollection) {
        System.out.println("\nTweets average from likes:\n");
        
        
         Bson group1 = group("$_avg", Accumulators.avg("average", "$likes"));
         
        List<Document> results = doc.aggregate(Arrays.asList(group1)).into(new ArrayList<>());
        System.out.println("results: " + results); 
}
```

Comment: It's Eclipse IDE for Java

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the "average" field:

```java
System.out.println("results: " + results.getDouble("average"));
```